# Вытянуть API с токеном через Python

Tags: python, api, python-3.5, token, аутентификация

Правильно задаю `url` (это точно):

```
url = ('https://aaaaa.bbbbbbb.online/api/rest/chat?'
       'filter[room]=5a32210e9279cbf1d027e449&populate=attach')
```

Не уверена, что правильно задаю аутентификацию (я так и не поняла, чем отличается задание её в `headers` и  в `auth`):

```
headers = {'Authorization' : 'X-access_token:xxxxxxxxxxxxx'}
```

Пытаюсь сделать запрос:

```
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
```

В итоге

```
print(r)
```

Даёт

```
<Response (404)>.
```

Помогите разобраться, в чем ошибка?

Comment: `end-point`-а вашего нет

Comment: добавьте  `print(r.text)` и `r.raise_for_status()`. И url вы все же неправильно задали

Comment: @AndrioSkur
    print(r.text) 
выдает ничего

r.raise_for_status() выдает ошибку:

HTTPError: 401 Client Error: Unauthorized for url: https://letovo.proctoring.online/api/rest/chat?filter[room]=5a32210e9279cbf1d027e449&populate=attach

url да, зачем-то в вопросе скрыла. В тексте ошибки правильный.

Comment: @Klimenkomud  url: https://letovo.proctoring.online/api/rest/chat?filter[room]=5a32210e9279cbf1d027e449&populate=attach

Comment: ну короче вам надо авторизоваться.(то есть код ошибки на самом деле 403). Как это вам сделать, мне не очень понятно, так как в инете не доки на этот апи

Comment: @AndrioSkur не поняла, что значит "нет доки на этот апи"

Comment: ну чтобы что-то удобно использовать, нужно чтобы было руководство на это что-то. Документация это и есть руководство. Вот была бы документация на этот апи, там было б написано что коннектиться надо таким образом. А так вы сделали ошибку, а где непонятно. И взять пример из документации вы тоже не можете, потому что её нет)

Comment: @AndrioSkur так. Ок. Допустим, я найду какого-то человека, который будет вместо документации именно к этому api (т.е. я правильно поняла, что имеется ввиду конкретно мой api с конкретно моим url?). Но мне хотя бы понять - у меян синтаксис в headers правильный или нет. Или я вообще мимо всё ставлю и это не headers

Comment: ну это headers и вы его правильно поставили

Comment: Вопрос снят, разобралась. Спасибо.

Comment: @MaxU могу )

правильный синтаксис для header:
    'headers = {'X-access-token' : 'ХХХХXXXXXXXXX'}'
т.к. X-access-token - это и есть вид заголовка.

Всё остальное правильно, запрос работает.

Comment: @MaxU где? не вижу.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75202/discussion-between-tatyana-aulova-and-andrio-skur).

Answer (score 2):

правильный синтаксис для header:

```
headers = {'X-access-token' : 'ХХХХXXXXXXXXX'}
```

т.к. X-access-token - это и есть вид заголовка. Всё остальное правильно, запрос работает, вытягивает данные.